# Setting a default Save type in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I finished making a template from WZTEMPLT and for it to work, it has to be saved to Excel Template 97 - 2003 type file.

But the thing I'm concerned is that I am afraid is that when I send the template to them, I scared they might send it back with a macro enable workbook instead of 'Excel 97-2003' file type and this will not work for me anymore.

So I am wondering if there is any way to have a defauly save type file.

Please advise, thanks for you time.

Are there any settings to help the case or is there macros that can be implied to help this problem.

Thanks

Comment: (1) You can add a save button to your worksheet and save it by a macro to the correct file type, but it doesn't prevent from a user choosing *Save as …* from the menu and choose any other format. (2) I would never send out a file containing a macro (most business policies block macros by default in their emails etc. Send out a worksheet only to collect data and import it into your macro-workbook. So you are independent from any format (3) I recommend not to use the old `xls` format with macros anymore we live in 2017 now.

Comment: But if you recommend me not to use WizTemplt (Since it's a very old addin) Is there any way to have a macro that can replace WizTemplt nicely?

Comment: Never heard of something like `WizTemplt`. If I google it I get 3 results 2 of them link to your question here. This is what I call ancient if it cannot be found by google.

Comment: oh dear.. It is an add on called 'Template Wizard' it's a really neat feature that once i press on 'Save' it automatically send the template's values into the database that is already been created

Comment: my bad, it's called WZTEMPLT @Peh

Comment: I can only recommend never to send any macro enabled files to business partners. I (and most companies too) would not accept macros anyway. Therefore the best solution is collect data with spreadsheets without macros. Anyway to answer your question: There is no way to prevent anyone saving this file in another format.